# Twitch client that notifies me when a followed streamer comes online

Tags: python, beginner, json, https

I've been writing code for a little while but I'm a little slapdash. I'd like to get better so I've been having a glance at best practices, other peoples code and reading a whole lot. I'd appreciate it if you could read through my code and make some suggestions and explain why. You'll find some of my code below.

I want to start writing more readable code, follow best practices and just be awesome. Suggested reading would also be appreciated.

```
import requests
import json
import winsound
import time
import sys

USERNAME = "lirik"
FIRST_RUN = True
VERSION_NO = 1.0

def main():

    print "%s [+] Twitch Notifier %s started..." % (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), VERSION_NO)
    print "%s [+] Loading follows from %s" % (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), USERNAME)
    try:
        twitch_data = requests.get("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/%s/follows/channels" % USERNAME)
    except:
        print "%s [+] Failed to contacted Twitch API" % time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        sys.exit(1)

    user_info = json.loads(twitch_data.text)  # load user data json into user_info
    users_online = list()  # initialise user_online list

    while True:
        for channel in user_info['follows']:  # Loop through channels in the users follow list
            stream_name = channel['channel']['name']  # Add channel name to var stream_name for simplicity
            try:
                stream_data = requests.get("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/%s" % stream_name)
            except:
                print stream_data.status_code
                print stream_data.text
                continue

            try:
                stream_info = json.loads(stream_data.text)
            except ValueError, e:
                print e
                continue

            if stream_info['stream']:
                if stream_name not in users_online:
                    print "%s [+] Online: %s [%s][%s]" % (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"),
                                                          stream_name,
                                                          stream_info['stream']['game'],
                                                          stream_info['stream']['viewers'])
                    users_online.append(stream_name)
                    winsound.Beep(1000, 1000)
            else:
                if stream_name in users_online:
                    print "%s [+]Checking if %s is offline." % (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"),
                                                                stream_name)
                    if chk_user_online(stream_name) is False:  #Double check if user is offline. Sometimes the twitch API fucks up.
                        print "%s [-] Offline: %s" % (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"),
                                                      stream_name)
                        users_online.remove(stream_name)
                else:
                    pass
                    #print "[*] No change in users online."

        if len(users_online) < 1 and first_run:
            first_run = False
            print "%s [*] There are currently no users online." % time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

        time.sleep(180)

def chk_user_online(streamer):

    try:
        stream_data = requests.get("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/%s" % streamer)
        stream_info = json.loads(stream_data.text)
    except:
        print "Stream check failed."
        return Exception("Failed to access stream data")

    if stream_info['stream'] is None:
        return False
    else:
        return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

It's good that you use absolute imports instead of wildcard imports.

> ```
> VERSION_NO = 1.0
> ```

While it is usually correct to use `ALLCAPS` for constants, the version number should be called `__version__`.  That way, the `help()` function will know which version the program is and will display it accordingly.

Using `%` for format strings is not officially deprecated, but it is recommended to use [.format()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) instead since it is more flexible.

When you have a `try:` block, you presumable know what errors could possibly happen.  You should list those errors in your `except:` statement.  That way, if one comes up that you didn't expect, you will know about it.  You might want to have two `except:` blocks: one for the errors you know about, and one for all the rest.  The second might be `except Exception as e: print e, "Something has gone wrong.  Please ..."` or whatever.

> ```
> except ValueError, e:
> ```

In Python2, you use parentheses around multiple errors that you want to catch, but the syntax used above means to call the error `e`.  In Python3, the parentheses are not needed, so what that line means is to catch all errors of type `ValueError` or of type `e`.  What you do in Python3 is to use `except ValueError as e:`  That is still possible in Python2, so to be in good practice, you should use it here.

> ```
> if stream_info['stream'] is None:
>     return False
> else:
>     return True
> ```

That's great that you used `is None` instead of `== None`.  Many people wouldn't do that.  The problem I have with this code is that `if ...` is checking if `...` is `True`.  Since you are already creating a boolean, take advantage of it and do it in one line:

```
return stream_info['stream'] is not None
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm having a bit of a mental block.

    `return stream_info['stream'] is not None`

By using the code it'll return True/False based on the conditions?

Comment: @Dan: Yes?  `stream_info['stream'] is not None` will be `False` if it is `None`, but `True` otherwise.

Comment: Thank you. I'll implement that right away. I'm really thankful for your kind but informative post. If anyone else has anything else to offer though that would be brilliant.